# mysql regexp in prepared statement trouble

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I'm making a filter system for a webshop, based on categories. These categories are saved with every piece of content in the database. The categories are intergers.

I am able to query the database directly, and this gives me the desired result.

`mysql> select id, name, category, url, price from content where category REGEXP '1|2|3|4|5|6';`

This returns

```
+----+------------+----------+--------------------------+-------+
| id | name       | category | url                      | price |
+----+------------+----------+--------------------------+-------+
|  1 | landschap1 |        2 | Ideal-landscape.jpg      |    20 |
|  2 | landschap1 |        2 | landscape-Photograps.jpg |    20 |
|  4 | landschap1 |        2 | landscape.jpg            |    25 |
|  5 | bunny      |        4 | bunny.mov                |   100 |
+----+------------+----------+--------------------------+-------+
```

When this is attempted in php however, I get a syntax error or access violation. Since the database user the code is using has no missing permissions this has to be a syntax error.

The query I'm trying to execute:

```
if(empty($_SESSION['filter'])){
    $halfFilt = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
$filter = implode('|', $halfFilt);
//If filter halfFilt is empty, assume no filter is selected.

$sql = "SELECT * FROM content WHERE id=:id AND WHERE category REGEXP :filter";
$sth->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindParam(':filter', $filter);
$sth->execute();
$results = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
return $results;
```

When i try to execute this query this is the error it throws:

`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE category REGEXP '1|2|3|4|5|6'' at line 1' in /var/www/portfolio/photoshop/include/database.php:89`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't related to the regular expression. You accidentally put an extra `WHERE` in your query. Replace it like this and it should hopefully work:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM content WHERE id=:id AND category REGEXP :filter";
```